# Use slashes in host file

Tags: hosts

I have the following line in my hosts file:

```
10.10.1.10 sub.domain.com
```

But `10.10.1.10` refers to the root of the server, which causes problems when I still have to go to a folder for example `10.10.1.10/myfolder`

The reason for the problem is that the online site does not have these folders, so I get errors when trying to check if a file exists.

When I change the line in the hosts file to

```
10.10.1.10/myfolder sub.domian.com
```

I get a blank page and not the same as when I actually type

```
10.10.1.10/myfolder
```

into my browser URL

My question is is there a way to use slashes correctly in the hosts file or perhaps an alternative?

Comment: In my site, I need the subdomain to specify which database should be used, so to do this when I add that line, it masks 10.10.1.10 as sub.domain.com. so when I type sub.domain.com in the browser, it shows me the content of 10.10.1.10. this is done so that I can test on my offline server exactly as it will work on the online site

Comment: so basically it shows the same thing as if I were to type 10.10.1.10, but I have the sub domain in my url so the site knows which DB to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosts file is used to map IP addresses to hostnames and vice versa.  Think of it as a poor man's DNS.  As such, the hosts file doesn't deal with path names, so the slashes aren't going to work.  It looks like you want sub.domain.com to redirect to `10.10.1.10/myfolder`.  This will require the remote server to do the redirection for you.

Comment: ahhh ohky, thanx!

Comment: I will just continue as it it was working correct offline

Answer (score 1):

> My question is is there a way to use slashes correctly in the hosts
>   file or perhaps an alternative?

No, you cannot add slashes (aka: directories, paths, etc…) to a hosts file. A network hostname is an alias for an IP address. Not a path on a server. Managing file paths is not the job of a networking tool of any kind.

The issues you are dealing with is the exact reason editing the hostile for web/application development is really a bad way to deal with what you are doing.

It’s much better to code your site to be accessible from other URLs on other ports so—for example—you could run the application on `localhost:8888` or even `localhost:3000`. Running on a different port completely avoids these issues.

And if somehow your code is based on a hostname—such as `sub.domain.com`—then you honestly should recode/reconfigure your code to be more flexible. Making your web sites and applications as portable as possible should be a skill that is very valuable to you as a developer and can even benefit your clients in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

To amplify the other answers, the original `hosts` entry allows you to address your web-site as `http://sub.domain.com` instead of `http://10.10.1.10`.

The first column in `hosts` is an IP address and nothing else. You can address your directory as either `http://sub.domain.com/MyFolder` or `http://10.10.1.10/MyFolder`.

When you say you don't have the directory on the live site, does this mean that you have separate subdomains for each site? If so, you can add the extra entries into `hosts`, eg:-

```
10.10.1.10    sub1.domain.com
10.10.1.10    sub2.domain.com
..........    ...............
10.10.1.10    subN.domain.com
```

If you do this, you can use whichever subdomain you want, and the web server can then identify which subdomain was addressed, so as to set the data-base appropriately.

Comment: The folder that I mentioned that does not exist online is because on the offline server I have multiple sites eg `10.10.1.10/site1`, `10.10.1.10/site1`, etc, where as online, those folders dont exist because the website domain is the folder

Comment: In that case, my update stands: map the web-site domains to 10.10.1.10 in `hosts`, and you mirror the on-line site exactly. After all, this is how hosting sites are able to support many different web-sites on the same IP address.